# Contacts Call Log

Tags: call-history

I have several hundred calls to one of my employees over the last 2 years. Every time I try to call up his contact information, the entire call history loads and it takes minutes. How can I prevent the call log from loading when I open contacts - it isn't helpful to me and I don't need it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! What device and Android version are you using? Call history usually is limited to something about 500 calls altogether, and shouldn't be loaded when opening contact details AFAIK (unless you touch the call log / call history tab, of course).